# How can remove console.log in the production build of a React application created using create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, console.log

How can remove console.log in the production build of a React application created using create-react-app CRA?

Comment: Self-answered questions must still be posted as a question and answer, and both must meet the quality requirements for any post. Also, why does this need another Q&A pair given that it's already in the one you've linked to?

Comment: Since faced issue in applying the solution in my app created using the create-react-app so I write it to help others

Comment: Nonetheless, please at least split it to a Q and A.

Comment: Thanks, @jonrsharpe for the suggestion. Hope this is the correct split now.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I am using this approach to avoid ejecting `react-scripts`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log = () => {}
  console.error = () => {}
  console.debug = () => {}
}
```

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './styles/main.scss'

// replace console.* for disable log on production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log = () => {}
  console.error = () => {}
  console.debug = () => {}
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: this is a great idea! as simple as it gets...

Comment: Awesome!!! Thanks

Comment: @Ali Turki, Did you face any performance issues in this case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26754011/5853931

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I know my env variables work based on other configurations, yet adding this doesn't seem to remove the console logs when running the react application locally. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about the parameters? Shouldn't it be something like `console.log = (..._) => {}`?

Answer (score 7):

I created a `helper` folder with a file called `ConsoleHelper.js`

```
const ConsoleHelper = (data) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') return;
  console.log(data);
}

export default ConsoleHelper;
```

So, instead of `console.log(data)` do `ConsoleHelper(data)`;

Comment: So simple yet so effective, no need to even mess with webpack! I added an option to pass a 2nd param since I usually also log out an object of some kind. Thanks so much for posting this!

Comment: @SpencerBigum anytime :)

Comment: The problem with this soluition is that the origin for this console msg will be ommitted and replaced with the location of your helper.

Comment: @ExisZhang I couldn't understand your comment. could you elaborate?

Comment: @arunvelsriram you lose the original file name and line number of the log, so it's pretty much useless. all your logs will come from ConsoleHelper.js line 3

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution using `craco`.

```json
"@craco/craco": "^6.0.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
```

`craco.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: (webpackConfig) => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        // remove console in production
        const TerserPlugin = webpackConfig.optimization.minimizer.find((i) => i.constructor.name === 'TerserPlugin');
        if (TerserPlugin) {
          TerserPlugin.options.terserOptions.compress['drop_console'] = true;
        }
      }

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: The subject specifically related to the CRA (create-react-app) where you are not able to set the webpack separately. So your solution is not relevant in this case.

Comment: @Ajay craco is a library specifically to allow you to set up webpack when using CRA. The solution is very relevant.

Comment: @efdee I haven't noticed yours this comment earlier. Thank

Comment: is it possible to only drop console.logs? leaving errors and warnings?

Answer (score 7):

This is my solution using `craco`

install https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console/

and update craco.config.js like

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [{ plugin: require('@semantic-ui-react/craco-less') }],
  babel: {
    // ...
  plugins: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? [["transform-remove-console", { "exclude": ["error"] }]] : []
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use CRACO, you don't need any third-party plugins, as in my previous answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67216067/8818057)

Comment: @weiliang i had tried that solution but some how it didn't work for me! so then i use this way to fix my issue

Answer (score 1):

For those not wanting to make changes to their webpack config, this expression does the job as well and without the need of importing a helper function:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" && console.log(data);
```

For larger or more verbosely logging applications, changing the webpack config is a more elegant solution of course.

**For VS Code users** i want point out the possibility to set [log points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_logpoints) and omit the statement altogether if that serves your need.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to create a new file in root named `logger.js`

In logger.js

```
var logger = function logger(...messages){
    if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'){
        console.log(messages);
    }
}
exports.logger = logger;
```

Now import this logger.js file to your components. For example my component file is demo.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
var logger = require('../logger.js').logger;

class Demo extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <p>Hello i am demo component</p>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        logger('I am printing only in developmet')
    }
}
export default Demo;
```

Comment: Its fine when start coding. But what will be with already written thousands lines of code.

Comment: @Ajay you could simply do a batch rename of all "console.log" to "logger" and then manually go importing it into all your files.

I don't really like this approach, I think it adds an easily avoidable import into pretty much all of your files. I think that the answer hello world is the right solution. You could just create a script that changes the drop_console param when you do something like install all your dependencies

Comment: this is also useless as you lose the original file and line number reference in the console

Answer (score -6):

The simple solution to the question is to help others who are facing the same issue.

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41041580/3574669

The suggestion in the reference, it needs to do a change in the file "webpack.config.js".  *The create-react-app uses the webpack and the config file internally but it is not possible to add webpack.config.js in my application root for applying the change. This would need to leave the create-react-app setup and build own setup for webpack and configuration. It does not find easy for me after exploring a lot and writing sample code.*

Since I am very much satisfied with create-react-app so also don't want to keep aside its benefits.

Finally, I did a simple change in the `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js` by adding a line `drop_console: true,` as mentioned in the reference. The suggested code in the reference is as below,

```
module.exports = {
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true, // Must be set to true if using source-maps in production
        terserOptions: {
          compress: {
            drop_console: true, // << this needs only to remove console.log //
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

This works fine to me and there is no console log in my production build application by the simple change.

I am using `"react-scripts": "3.0.1",`

**Note: This new line will be cleaned whenever you reinstall "react-scripts" later. So it would need to again do the same change in such an event.**

#### *IMPORTANT: Don't use this approach if using CI/CD*

Comment: How this got 2 upvotes is beyond me.
You should never alter code in node_modules as Ajay mentions himself, a simple npm i will just override it, if you want to change the code in one of the repos you're using so much, just fork it and use it locally.

Comment: @naor.z I have suggested a single change and a simple precaution. It is easy to implement and maintainable for novice developers as well. Forking and changing are not so simple. Also, this doesn't need any additional effort in making helper as suggested by "hello world" and replace the "console.log" within the entire codes. Please suggest any other solution if simpler than what I have suggested.

Comment: -1 for really dangerous approach. Simple - yes, wrong - YES. Project with few of these approaches is unmaintainable for any serious work.  There are two options:
#1 Eject the config
#2 Use https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired to alter WebPack options 

I prefer option 2

Comment: @zveljkovic The solution is not the best but simple and maintainable for the specific purpose since only one line to maintain. For a very large project and multiple changes in the config, I may agree with your 2 options. But I don't understand why the specific approach for the specific purpose is dangerous since it will not break the code?

Comment: People use SO to find answers and they are also used in production/live code. Change of node_module dependencies will not work in CD/CI environments where the `npm i` is used to initialize the deps. #2 above is simple and generally safe. Look at it like this: "You can use the knife as screwdriver but it's not the way to do the job".

Comment: Agreed. Will check #2. Thanks

Comment: Any change you make to files under node_modules will be lost when running on a machine other than the one where you made the change. This is probably the _worst answer of all_.

Comment: If the purpose of your answer is to help newbies, then you are doubly wrong. Setting such an example for beginners is either deliberate sabotage or some kind of sloppiness. As has been said several times, this advice is fundamentally problematic because no one ever edits installed dependencies that are derived from package.json. All your changes will be overwritten on subsequent reinstalls and will never end up on any other machine. Fork and install your patched package!