# Is it OK to leave console.log() calls in production code?

Tags: javascript

Regarding the "console.log" function, is it used only for testing/debugging purposes? So would I have to remove them for the final coding stage where everything is completed?
I'm confused. For instance, when I'm declaring a function, how would I change the following?

`function greeting() {
console.log('Hello World');
}`

I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: It's not a stupid question, but unfortunately it's not a question fit for StackOverflow (I voted to close as *"opinion based"*). It depends on the programmer. For instance, I always remove all `console.log`s, but sometimes I leave some `console.info` and `console.warn`, just to log some important information for other users/programers. I've seen big websites, made by professionals, logging all kinds of stuff, like arrays or objects. It must be said, however, that too much `console.log` will have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: "too much console.log will have a negative impact on performance". @GerardoFurtado could I get a link to an article/documentation that describes this? 

p.s. New to JS.

Comment: @kalpajagrawalla you'll find some info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11426185/5768908. Actually, this doesn't even need a  benchmark, empirical evidence is enough: when you have a `console.log` inside a loop you can clearly see that the code is hundreds or thousands of times slower.

Answer (score 4):

`console.log` or any console methods are for showing any information on browser developer console

It varies, `Production` env means it's solely for end `user` and everything is correct to make your website useful. That is why websites have `dev`/ `QA`/ `Stage` env where you want to have some information for `developers`.

`console.log` or any methods associated to `console` uses developer `console` of the browser, with that said it's clear that it totally meant for someone who is using your website more then just getting information `[hacker, developer, auditor, ]` etc.

For `End user` which we expect to be just the normal people who are on your website for their need and don't have any technical requirement, then loggin an `error` to console is useless ! Instead you need some kind of pop up or notification to inform end user that something went wrong or any useful information.

But there is kind of useful scenarios which you want to inform user to avoid any bad activity suggested by any hacker. Like `facebook` does, as many of the hacker uses `JS` snippets to do some automatic changes to website ask normal users to use console and post their snippets. In this case `console` methods are useful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is used for outputting/logging text to the console. It is not necessary to remove it when you release the web app/website.

For more information on how to use `console.log`, click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log).

Answer (score 1):

It is mainly for printing relevant info to the browsers console window, although there is a better alternative for debugging. See [debugger statement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp). I would not leave console.logs lying around all over the place whereas it would seem a bit sloppy. Besides, it could be harder to follow depending on how many there are.

There are however times when you would want to leave the console logs and those times are merely for conditional local or server environment execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be used only for testing/debugging purposes. I would suggest not to use it even for debugging/testing purposes. Better, start a debugger, attach a breakpoint on a statement that you want to analyze and you are sorted.

Example in https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Comment: “Yes” remove, or “yes” ok to leave in?

Comment: Remove it. Why you want to print unnecessary stuff on the users browsers.