# Will console block the page rendering

Tags: javascript, html, web-performance

I wrote a html page with code below。

```
<html>
<header>
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html" title="Coyle Appliance Repair"></a></div>
    <div class="phoneNumber"><h3 class="numberHeader">call today for an appointment - same day service is available</h3>
        <h1 class="number"><a href="tel:+1-555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a></h1></div>
    <div class="greyStrip"><h2 class="motto">Serving the Twin Cities and western Wisconsin since 1982</h2></div>
</header>

<script>
  ((function demo () {
    let a = 1
    while (a < 10000) {
      a++

      console.log(a)
    }
  })())
</script>

<div class="mainContent"><h2 class="missionStatement">Full service restaurant and commercial kitchen repair. We service all cooking, food prep, warewash/dishroom, and
    refrigeration equipment.</h2>
</div>
</html>
```

Question is，what the difference between keep and remove the code of `console.log(a)`

1. When i remove it, the page will display fluently with no block or a flash.
2. But when i add this console, the page will block a period of time or with a flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is calculating each iteration of that loop and running all the code inside. Every function uses something, in this case you are calling that `console.log` **10,000** times which means the browser has to do at least **10,000** calculations.

The `console.log` will not *block* the page from rendering but it can hinder the performance of the page rendering, hence why you are getting that flickering effect.

How console.log affects performance: [console.log is a lot slower than an empty function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26754011/11404295)

Comment: @d_30 if this is the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as accepted. It helps me, and the community, out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting, `console.log` can cause more fatal issues (failed page loads) in older browsers, so if you don't need it in production, take it out as it's unnecessary dross regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any function call will slightly reduce the performance. And in your code, you call console.log about 10000 times, so it'll make the page's performance reduced.