# How to log a message to the web developer console - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I log a custom Message to the web development console? If so,how?

If you check this console for example:

```
http://passion4web.co.uk/ben/pong
```

The console logs a message when you press keys. I want to do it so that when my JavaScript loads on to my page it displays a message in the console like

```
"JavaScript file - ENABLED".
```

(If it can't be in JavaScript I will take jQuery too)

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log(msg) to log things to the console.

[Console.log()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: It's that simple? ... Seriously?

Comment: Yes :) Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
console.log('message');
```

But be aware of: [Is it a bad idea to leave "console.log()" calls in your producton JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114187/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-leave-firebug-console-log-calls-in-your-producton-javascri)