# Stripping all comments and console.logs with ng build --prod, possible?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using MEAN, Angular 2, Node/Express, Angular-CLI and ng build --prod to build my app and I have a travesty of commented out throwaway code and a billion debugging console.log statements throughout my app. Is there a way to have the build process remove all comments and console.log statements when it builds? The thought of doing it manually is scary!

Comment: I'd imagine the comments are already removed, have you looked at the output? But how is it supposed to know which logs are functionality and which just debugging?

Comment: angular-cli uses webpack under the hood, which is already doing some kind of mangling of the javascript during the bundling process.  I believe there's plugins for webpack to remove console logging and also comments during the mangle process, but I'm not sure how to sync that up with angular-cli.

Comment: You can use Gulp with gulp-strip-debug. Check out [this article](https://medium.com/@jun711.g/how-to-remove-console-log-from-your-javascript-files-programmatically-469eed2ec8fe) for more information.

Comment: please remove commented blocks and console.log statements from the CODE to save future developers their sanity.  This is how wars get started.

Answer (score 45):

I have simple fix. Put this code in `main.ts`

```
if(env === 'prod') { // assuming you have env variable configured
  // check if window exists, if you render backend window will not be available 
  if(window){
      window.console.log = function(){};
   }
}
```

Comment: lol nice idea, problem is I have more console.log statements in my server-side code :P thanks though

Comment: You can do the same on server code too. Put that code in `server.js`. Don't attach to window though because it does not exist in node env.

Comment: gr8 idea... u saved my day. :)

Comment: I have used it in my main.ts, but this is not working! My webpack version is 3.5.5, does it have something to do with webpack version?

Comment: Any update on this? Is this still a viable solution? Also, how exactly does this work? It simply intercepts all console logs and so that prevents anything from being printed in the console?

Comment: Yes, its simply overriding the prototype method with an empty function.

Comment: This worked for me!  I added this in my main.ts as below:
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  if(window){
      window.console.log = function(){};
   }
}

Comment: Surprised this is the accepted solution here. This doesn't strip console.log. It simply changes `console.log` to do nothing. That will impact any javascript running in the current window, not just your own. This is a terrible practice. A better solution would be for webpack to strip the console.log calls from the files during the bundling/minification process.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this bc the browser stills executes the placeholder function, which is still CPU effort for the users device. See: https://www.codementor.io/brijmcq/angular-clear-all-of-your-console-logs-in-production-build-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-cxcw30yqs#comment-sjclji9d8

Answer (score 16):

Simply add this `window.console.log = function(){};` to `

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}`
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this bc the browser stills executes the placeholder function, which is still CPU effort for the users device. See: https://www.codementor.io/brijmcq/angular-clear-all-of-your-console-logs-in-production-build-with-just-a-few-lines-of-code-cxcw30yqs#comment-sjclji9d8

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ng lint` with `--fix` flag and `no-console` rule in tslint configuration file. And hook it to your build call in your package file.

eg.:

`...
 "prebuild": "ng lint --fix",
 "build": "ng build -prod",
...`

and build the app

`npm run build`

ref: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/lint

Comment: is `npm run build` the same as running `ng build --prod` ?

Comment: Yes, but the `prebuild ` commend won't trigger.
You can make two calls though:
`ng lint --fix && ng build -prod`

Comment: I like the idea, but running lint with --fix option doesn't actually remove the console uses in my files. Any idea why?

Comment: My bad... 

`no-console` doesn't have a fixer

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

Comment: An other option would be to use webpack.
You can generate the config by hitting:
`ng eject`
And the use the loader `webpack-strip`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-strip

Hope it helps!

Comment: Careful with `ng eject` as you will then be forced to manage webpack yourself going forward, and is not easy to reverse this process.

Comment: This is an old thread but I'd 100% advise against `ng eject` - I've worked on projects with custom webpack and cli and going back to cli after ejection is a total PAIN - not to mention configuring/updating without the cli is a slow process.

Answer (score 2):

Another not completely explained option is (if linting or custom webpack isn't the way to go):

To strip the log statements from the code by your build.

So, here is what I have done (I use nx on top of Angular CLI):

1. Adding a custom script that cleans all console.log calls

`utils/clean-console.log.js`

```
const glob = require('glob');
const replace = require('replace');

// list all directories you want to scan
// (I have a nx mono.repo with multiple involved projects & libs)
[
    './apps/<app>/src/**/*.ts',
    './libs/*/src/**/*.ts',
].forEach(pattern => glob(pattern, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    files.forEach(item => replace({
        // change to your needs which levels you want to strip
        // the levels listed are removed from code
        regex: /.*console\.(log|info|debug|warn)\([^\)]*\);?.*/gm,
        replacement: '',
        paths: [item],
    }));
}));
```

2. Updating `package.json` for my build command

```
node utils/clean-console.log.js && nx run <app>:build:prod
```

---

This works for me pretty nicely (even for multiline log statements) since I have a consistent code style. Every log statement is followed by a new line. If you don't have that, you can't use the script right ahead.

Btw. you change the code with this. But for me in pipeline context it doesn't matter since every build will be checked out again & what happens to the code inside the pipeline doesn't matter. Only the compiled output does matter...

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to do the same for the other consoles

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
    if(window){
      window.console.log = function(){};
      window.console.warn = function(){};
      window.console.error = function(){};
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide all the `console.log()` in production (angular) by two ways.

They are

1. hiding throughout the angular app
2. hinding them in particular component only.

- **Hiding throughout the app**

open `main.ts` file and add the following lines inside production check condition

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();

  if (window) {
    window.console.log = function() {};
  }
}
```

or

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  window.console.log = function() {};
}
```

- **Hiding in particular component only**

Open that component's component.ts file and add the following code inside ngOnInit life cycle hook

```
import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
....

ngOnInit() {
    if (!isDevMode()) {
      console.log = function() {};
    }
}
```

This will hide them only in that particular component.

If you wanna hide them in IE, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733807/disabling-console-log-in-production)

if you get linting error for not using normal function, replace it with the following arrow function

```
console.log = () => {};
```