# Different bet text vs console error logging in Angular

Tags: angular, error-handling

I am developing application using Angular & I want to know recommended way to use error logging.

My query is should I go for console logging or text based logging as text based logging stores historical error information on server which later can be use for debugging. but this will also use server space while for console log there is no way to track error if customer close the browser & even don't remember how to re-generate it.

Comment: May be this is purely opinion based , If you think you need to track error logs you can go for text logging or may be you can use `console.log` for development purpose.

Comment: Ok. I am thinking to use console for development & text based for production environment.

Comment: right , even you can set different behaviour on the basis of enviroment

Comment: Yes I found other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656092/angular-console-log-only-on-development-environment) for how to use different behaviour. Thanks

Comment: yeah exactly the same I was suggesting you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can choose error.service to send you log when catched an error with mail or you can add a simple db (end of day a cron jobs works daily which remove logs). Console.log output also shows you history of the error. So, you can reproduce error .

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rr28hm

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  error: string = null;

  constructor() {
    try {
      throw new Error("hi, i am an error!");
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = JSON.stringify(error.stack);
      console.log(this.error);
      // this.http.post("url", { data: this.error }).subscribe((response) => console.log("POST: error saved to db: ", response));
    }
  }
}
```

When you parse error string you will see the error line number and history.

Comment: Even after browser close it is able to show historical error if customer did this after issue? We don't want to install any browser extension on client PC.

Comment: Maybe you can add event trigger while window.unload(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload