# Disabling console.log() in production

Tags: typescript, internet-explorer, angular5, angular-cli

I have run the following to disable console logs for production environments in my angular application.  The below code works as expected for chrome, however, it still shows logs in IE 11.

main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
if(window){
  window.console.log=function(){};
 }
}
```

Is this a polyfill issue?  I wasn't able to find anything online about it.

EDIT

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code) may seem similar but does not address my issue as to why overriding the console log function to a blank method works in chrome but not IE 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Comment: The suggestions there work for the chrome browser but not in IE 11 (the issue)

Comment: I just found this, seems relevant: https://www.beyondjava.net/console-log-surprises-with-internet-explorer-11-and-edge

Comment: I was hopeful but that doesn't seem to work for IE 11

Comment: @NathanielFlick - Apologies but I think the poly fiill in your console log surprises link worked!

Comment: no worries glad it worked!

Comment: https://devsuhas.com/2023/02/18/angular-disable-console-log-in-production/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution is to add the polyfill to your polyfill.ts file

```
if(!window.console) {
 var console = {
  log : function(){},
  warn : function(){},
  error : function(){},
  time : function(){},
  timeEnd : function(){}
 }
}
```

Comment: From your last post, I can see that your issue is solved now and you had posted the solution. I suggest you to mark that solution as an accepted answer for this question after 24 hrs may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @Deepak-MSFT, I had forgotten.  Hopefully it does help someone in the future.

Answer (score 21):

The question has been answered and the answer has been accepted, but I want to show you a better way to disable/switch-off console.log in production.
under **src/envirenmonts** add an **environment.ts** with the following content:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,

  mode: 'Dev'
}
```

In the **main.ts** import the **envirenmont** *const*:

```
import './polyfills';
...
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

Now add the following code-snippet:

..

```
if (environment.production) {
      window.console.log = () => { }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {
  ...
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

To try this, add a **console.log** in the constructor of the **app.component.ts**:

```
...
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  ...
  constructor() {    
    console.log('How to switch off logging in Production?')
  }
}
```

Switch the **environment.production** to *true/false* to see the result
Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-switch-off-logging-in-production)

Comment: thanks! I like this solution, other env should show the logs and this what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a custom log function in Utility.ts class as follows

```
    public static log(strValue: string) {
    if (CoreService._env !== 'prod') {
      console.log(strValue);
    }
  }
```

Where _env variable defined in CoreService and assigned value inside app. component as follows

```
this.coreService.env = environment.env;
```

In environment.ts file define env as follows

```
export const environment = { env: 'dev'} // for production it will be 'prod'
```

And my component is using

```
Utility.log("Print the value");
```

That way, you can easily prevent logs on production.

Answer (score 1):

This solution for works for all Angualr, ReactJS, VueJS and Vanilla JavaScript etc.

You can `enable` / `disable` by this way!

```js
console.log("Before disabled logs");

const consoleLog = false

if(!consoleLog) {
  console.log = function() {} 
}

console.log("After disabled logs #1");
console.log("After disabled logs #2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have cretated a little library for issues like this: [deblog](https://github.com/msalafia/deblog). You don't have to rewrite the console object methods.

You can create a wrapper of the console object and define proper methods for logging that you can configure as you wish and disable them for production:

For instance, you can do something like this:

```js
import { createDeblog } from "deblog";

const configuration = {
  logs: [
    {
      name: "foo",
      level: "debug",
      tag: "FOO -",
      enabled: true,  // <- THIS can be set using a PRODUCTION_LOG variable set to "false"
    },
    {
      name: "bar",
      level: "log",
      tag: `[${new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleTimeString()}] BAR -`,
    },
  ],
};

let dlog = createDeblog(configuration);

dlog.disableAllBut("bar"); // Silencing all logs but bar

dlog.foo("1 Connection Error"); // Will not be logged
dlog.bar("I'm here!");
dlog.foo("2 Connection Error"); // Will not be logged
dlog.bar("I just need bar logs here");

dlog.restoreAll();

dlog.bar("4 Connection Error"); // Will be logged
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. The answer also needs to contain more information than *just* a link to your content, e.g. you could add usage information to the answer. Please update all the recent answers you've posted that link to your content like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
     
    @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 
    
    export class ConsoleToggleService { 
       constructor() {}
    
       disableConsoleInProduction(): void { 
         if (environment.production) {
           console.warn(` Console output is disabled on production!`);
           console.log = function (): void { };
           console.debug = function (): void { };
           console.warn = function (): void { };
           console.info = function (): void { };
         }
       }
    }
```

Finally, in your AppComponent, inject the ConsoleToggleService and call the disableConsoleInProduction() function in the constructor, like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private consoleToggleService: ConsoleToggleService) {
     this.consoleToggleService.disableConsoleInProduction();
  }
}
```