# Git Hub Action remove console.log()

Tags: github, github-actions, github-pages

I am learning the GitHub action now I have my project which consists of Angular as the front end and WordPress as the backend. For testing purposes, I have used a lot of console.log() functions for testing purposes. Now I want when I deploy or commit to the Git Hub it automatically removes all the logs so it won't be visible on deployed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Find and Replace](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/find-and-replace) action to replace all the `console.log()` occurrences as an intermediate step before deployment.

For example:

```yaml
name: Deploy
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Find and Replace
        uses: jacobtomlinson/gha-find-replace@v2
        with:
          find: "console\.log\(([^)]+)\)"
          replace: ""
          regex: true

      # deployment steps
```

Also, I would recommend disabling `console.log()`s in production as an alternative. [Disabling console.log() in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733807/disabling-console-log-in-production).

P.S. I'm not sure if regex is correct, it should be tested well. Took it [here](https://www.regextester.com/96938).