# How to console.log() an Angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

I have been trying to debug an Angular project with `console.log()`, and I checked my chrome console logging options and made sure that all the levels are enabled, but I still got nothing as an output.

I placed my `console.log()` in many places in the code, including at the constructor of a class and it still didn't work. I noticed; however, that I get an output at the chrome console when I change `console.log()` to `console.error()`. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Is `console.log` overriden somewhere?

Comment: Are you actually logging something like `console.log(“something”)`

Answer (score 3):

Just try with a hard-coded string in console.log like "console.log("something") and check if it printing.
Otherwise, you can also place "debugger" in your code where you want to pause your application. Using this will ensure that whether the control is actually going in that block of code or not. After that press F12 and run your application.

Answer (score 0):

It may possible, Logging level has been enabled. You can look for below given code to disable it.

```
if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}`
```

There might chance, log is disabled on `lint` level. When u disable in lint level, on run of `ng lint --fix`. It remove lower log level. Check your `tslint config` for more info.

```
ng lint --fix
```

**More info:**
[Stripping all comments and console.logs with ng build --prod, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307317/stripping-all-comments-and-console-logs-with-ng-build-prod-possible)